# How to create custom UINavigationController class with custom init?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, initializer

I tried to create a custom `UINavigationController` class as follows-

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController {
    private let user: User

    init(user: User, rootViewController: UIViewController) {
        self.user = user
        super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

The above code fails at runtime with the following error-

> Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(nibName:bundle:)' for class 'app.NavigationController'

I tried to resolve the issue by adding the initializer

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController {
    private let user: User

    init(user: User, rootViewController: UIViewController) {
        self.user = user
        super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

The compiler throws the error "Property 'self.user' not initialized at super.init call".

Is there a way to solve this problem without making `user` property as implicitly unwrapped optional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following :

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController {
    private let user: User

    init(user: User, rootViewController: UIViewController, nibName nibNameOrNil: String? = nil, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle? = nil) {
        self.user = user
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.viewControllers = [rootViewController]
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
let vc = UIViewController()
let nc = NavigationController(user: User(), rootViewController: vc)
```

Answer (score 1):

use convenience init with custom params and call designated initializer to set root viewController

```
final class NavigationController: UINavigationController {
    
    private var user: User?
    
    convenience init(rootViewController: UIViewController, user: User) {
        self.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)
        self.user = user
    }
    
    override init(rootViewController: UIViewController) {
        super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

/// How to use

let user = User()
let rootViewController = UIViewController()
let navigationController = NavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController, user: user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't **initialize** user like this. 
In the **Controller** where you call this `NavigationController`:

- change `private let user : User` to

  `var user : User!`
- init your NavigationController
- then set user like this:

  `navigationController.user = self.user`

Where `self.user` is the **variable** that you want to give the `navigationController`

Answer (score 0):

The method

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?)
```

is the designated initialiser which means that it will always get called, while

```
init(rootViewController: )
```

is a convenience initialiser which may get called for convenience reasons. When the designated initialiser gets called your class has an uninitialised user constant. You can switch user to be an optional var and have it initialised with nil.